# Payemnt Method in Woocommerce how to get meta of this method?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, hook-woocommerce

I have added EVERTEC as woocommerce Payment Method https://www.evertecinc.com

[image]

As you can see here what I have set as Evertec Username & Evertec Password I want to get Username and Password on Checkout Page how can I get their value and set it on Checkout Page?

Comment: It might be in wp_option table, not in meta

Comment: I find it in wp_options but using Woocommerce Hook how can I get that values in my checkout form Page? @Tristup

Comment: I am unable to find the plugin to install my end and  guide you properly.

Comment: can you provide me the option_key and the value with it, so I can try it

Comment: I am creating the plugin from my own side there is no plugin available for this Payment method. I just want to know how to get this dynamic options in front end to hidden fields from where I can redirect it to payment gateway rightnow I am putting it as static so it is redirecting

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `get_option` function to get the details. Place the **key** as parameter to `get_option`.

Hope it will work for you.